# Passing parameter list ot blazor component

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, c#-7.0

I want to pass a list of parameters to a blazor component like this

```
   <PassingOptions >
            <UnitParams>
                <UnitParam UnitName="kg" isDefault="True"
                        AbsoluteValidate="true" AbsoluteMinimumValue="1" AbsoluteMaximumValue="499"
                         NormalRangeValidate="true" NormalMinimumValue="3" NormalMaximumValue="99" />
                <UnitParam UnitName="lb" isDefault="False"
                        AbsoluteValidate="true" AbsoluteMinimumValue="2" AbsoluteMaximumValue="999"
                        NormalRangeValidate="true" NormalMinimumValue="6" NormalMaximumValue="199" />
            </UnitParams>
        </PassingOptions>
```

Below is my attempt of setting up the control to receive them but it doesn't work
any help would be appreciated.

Obviously I could create UnitParams in the C# for the page and bind it to the control as a single parameter but IMO its tidier and easier to work on like above

```
namespace BlazorPatient.Shared.FormControls
{
    public partial class PassingOptions : ComponentBase
    {
        [Parameter]
        public List<UnitParam> UnitParams { get; set; }
    }
    public class UnitParam
    {
        [Parameter]
        public string UnitName { get; set; }

        [Parameter]
        public Boolean isDefault { get; set; }
        [Parameter]

        public Boolean AbsoluteValidate { get; set; }
        [Parameter]

        public decimal AbsoluteMinimumValue { get; set; }
        [Parameter]

        public decimal AbsoluteMaximumValue { get; set; }
        [Parameter]

        public Boolean NormalRangeValidate { get; set; }
        [Parameter]

        public decimal NormalMinimumValue { get; set; }
        [Parameter]

        public decimal NormalMaximumValue { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a hunch, but have you tried initializing the list in the constructor of  PassingOptions ? So UnitParams = new List<UnitParam>(); It could also be that List needs added items, so perhaps try a IEnumerable.

Comment: Thanks. Tried changing to IEnumerable and adding a constructor but still doesnt seem to work

Comment: You can't do it that way - the component thinks those blocks are either new components or render fragments, not data objects.  You need to pass a data object as you obviously don't want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I know this is not exactly what you wanted but I think it might be a good jumping off point

### HTML in Page

```
<ChildType UnitParams="@(new List<UnitParam>(){
                   new UnitParam("kg", true, true, 1, 499, true, 3, 99),
                   new UnitParam("lb", false, true, 2, 999, true, 6, 199)
               })"/>
```

### Param in Child

```
[Parameter]
public List<UnitParam> UnitParams { get; set; }
```

### Code for UnitParam

```
public class UnitParam
{
    public string UnitName { get; set; }
    
    public bool isDefault { get; set; }
    
    public bool AbsoluteValidate { get; set; }
    
    public decimal AbsoluteMinimumValue { get; set; }
    
    public decimal AbsoluteMaximumValue { get; set; }
    
    public bool NormalRangeValidate { get; set; }
    
    public decimal NormalMinimumValue { get; set; }

    public decimal NormalMaximumValue { get; set; }

    public UnitParam(string unitName, bool isDefault, bool absoluteValidate, decimal absoluteMinimumValue, decimal absoluteMaximumValue, bool normalRangeValidate, decimal normalMinimumValue, decimal normalMaximumValue)
    {
        UnitName = unitName;
        this.isDefault = isDefault;
        AbsoluteValidate = absoluteValidate;
        AbsoluteMinimumValue = absoluteMinimumValue;
        AbsoluteMaximumValue = absoluteMaximumValue;
        NormalRangeValidate = normalRangeValidate;
        NormalMinimumValue = normalMinimumValue;
        NormalMaximumValue = normalMaximumValue;
    }
}
```

As was already mentioned in the comments to your question the way wou wanna do it requires render fragments, which just isnt appropriate for the usage.

If you wanna know the reason for the @() its quite simple. This lets you use "" inside the Attribute "".